# EF Core - Saving changes are not adding new record

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I looked on many threads on Stack but did not found any solution. I have simple code to add record to table containing only one column - primary key. Like this:

```cs
public partial class XSavedList
{
   public int XId { get; set; }
}
```

I use this table as list to save already processed numbers. I want to add some number through EF Core:

```cs
private static void AppendNewNumberInSavedList(int id)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new xContext())
        {
            var newObject =
                new XSavedList()
                {
                    XId = id
                };

            db.XSavedList.Add(newObject);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This method is launched by creation of Task with Action of this method and `.Start();` somewhere in the code.

My problem is - after `db.SaveChanges();` in `DebugView` of `ChangeTracker` inside context, I can see my added record with state `Unchanged`. In effect, EF Core is not adding new record to database. Before `SaveChanges();` the same record in `DebugView` is showing state `Added`. No exception, can't tell why EF didn't add records.

Specs: .NET 5.0 / EF Core 5.0.9 / MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.5 / VS2019

Comment: Maybe because you have not awaited Task. Try without starting task. Also MySql.EntityFrameworkCore is buggy provider even worse it does not support async operations. Use `Pomelo` provider instead.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Elaborate, please. Why should I try without starting task? Why should I await creation of Task by constructor? Method is running, I can tell states of object before and after saving changes. Changes are not saving, no matter how long I will wait for it. For provider, I have bad experiences with Pomelo (literally couldn't use it properly, on EF Core 3.1 it was so buggy I surrender really quickly) so I stick with official provider.

Comment: Well, your code works without additional task?

Comment: What is lifecycle of your context? Do you create new context for each task? Because DbContext is not thread-safe.

Comment: Can you show us the `xContext` class? As @ToldaCakir pointed, how do you associate your context to your database?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the database which you checked? You might be checking the wrong database. Please be sure what your connection string and server/database parameters are the same.